How to redirect after sign up laravel jetstream
On laravel jetstream, after I changed the line ('home' => '/dashboard',) to ('home' => '/dashboard',) in fortify file. When I sign up successfull, the system do not direct me to index page, it still stay on register page but it display the interface of index page on a small window like the picture. And after I reload page, it direct me to dashboard page.
enter image description here
I try to edit the RegisterUserController but it did not work
My route Web.php: enter image description here
My RegisterController file: enter image description here

The community can't help you if you don't provide the minimal, reproducible, relevant code.

@Robert Sorry my bad, I added more information on my question
